# Как запустить easyjson в golang

Tags: golang

Столкнулся с кодогенерацией в golang, не могу разобраться с easyjson от mail.ru.
Установил easyjson как написано в инструкции `go get -u github.com/mailru/easyjson/...`, далее в проекте создал отдельный пакет в котором имеется только один файл models.go со структурой.

```
package models

//easyjson:json
type User struct {
    Name     string
    Email    string
    Phone    string
}
```

Далее, по инструкции сказано настроить переменную GOPATH. Указал на папку с проектом.
Последнее, что требуется, выполнить команду `easyjson -all models.go`
Но при выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
easyjson : Имя "easyjson" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также налич 
ие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ easyjson -all models.go
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (easyjson:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Пробовал искать информацию в интернете, но почти все ответы сводятся к двум пунктам:

1. установить
2. запустить команду

Подскажите, как можно решить данную проблему. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. При установки easyjson, в bin появился exe файл. Нужно было указать путь до него.